# Custom inputs for bootstrap x-editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

We are using the [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable) jQuery/bootstrap plugin.

Something we cannot work out how to do is custom displays,
Essentially we display the users location as `city/COUNTRY` e.g. `Napier/NEW ZEALAND`

Now what we want is when the user clicks on the editable containing this data we need a popover that has
a `text input` for the city and a `select` for the country. We then need to send this off to the server as two different keys aka

```
{
    city: 'Napier',
    country: 'nz'
}
```

Well, at least that would be ideal, we could get away with sending `value: 'Napier|nz'`, I could work this part out myself, the thing I don't get is how to display the two different fields in the popover?

Here is a jsFiddle playground: http://jsfiddle.net/KYvAC/

Comment: Check out the [demo page](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html) for x-editable, they have an example for an address with multiple fields. The JS for that is located [here](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/assets/x-editable/inputs-ext/address/address.js) maybe that can give you an idea of how to implement yours

Comment: Cheer's that's got me going in the right step, next question is... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653901/x-editable-custom-field-type-not-respecting-overridden-defaults