# x-editable custom fields cannot get text of select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

Ive followed this example from another SO thread:
[X-editable custom field type not respecting overridden defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653901/x-editable-custom-field-type-not-respecting-overridden-defaults)
 and its helped me to create a similar custom field with x-editable. All is working ok but i cant figure out how render/display the 'text' of the select - the SO example ouputs the 'value'. my js to initialis the x-editable to use my custom inputs is thus:

```
          $('#stffulladdress').editable({
        url      : '',
        pk       : 6,
        value    : {
            address  : "",
            city     : "",
            region   : "",
            postcode : "",
            country  : "eng"
        },
        sourceCountry: [
            { value: "eng", text: "ENGLAND" },
            { value: "ire", text: "IRELAND" },
            { value: "sco", text: "SCOTLAND" },
            { value: "cym", text: "WALES" }
        ],
        validate : function(value) {
          if (value.address == '' || value.postcode == '') return "Address first lines AND Postcode required";
        },

        display  : function(value) {
          if (!value) {
            $(this).empty();
            return;
          }
          console.log(value.country);
          var html = $('<div>').html( value.address + '<br />' + value.city + '<br />' + value.region + '<br />' + value.postcode + '<br />' + value.country );
          $(this).html(html);
        }
      });
```

My custom x-editable class is the same as the SO example mentioned with the only difference being i have more inputs -they work ok as expected. I would have thought that this snippet from the x-edit class gets the text of the selected item:

```
        value2html: function(value, element) {
        if(!value) {
            $(element).empty();
            return; 
        }
        var countryText = value.country;
        $.each(this.sourceCountryData, function (i, v) {
            if (v.value == countryText) {
                countryText = v.text.toUpperCase();
            }
        });
        var html = $('<div>').html( value.address + ',<br />' + value.city + ',<br />' + value.region + ',<br />' + value.postcode + ',<br />' + countryText );
        $(element).html(html); 
    },
```

But upn displaying the selected country i still get the country value "eng" and not the text "England".

I've tried :

> **value.country** which gives me the value 'eng'
>   and **value.text** gives undefined

Any idea how i can get the selected text??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the sourceCountry as follow:

```
sourceCountry: [
    { "eng": "ENGLAND" },
    { "ire": "IRELAND" },
    { "sco": "SCOTLAND" },
    { "cym": "WALES" }
],
```